# Possible human infantry weaponry 200 years from now

Tags: technology, weapons

Basically my story is about this guy who dies and wakes up a god of his own world where he makes an entirely new race from scratch. Long story short, humans arrive on his world to attempt to colonize it and a big fight ensues. He awakens as a god 200 years after his death on earth, which would put his death at 2000, and the year of his awakening at 2200. Any ideas on possible realistic weaponry?

Comment: The answer to this depends greatly on what scientific breakthroughs happen in the next 200 years.  Consider that *no one* could predict the weapons of today before the computer revolution a mere 70 years ago.

Comment: In a world 200 years ago weapons we use today were hard to imagine. Impossible, even.

Comment: As stands, this is on the broad side.  It would help if you could look up what weaponry is currently used and restrict to replacements for that.  Do you want lethal weaponry or non-lethal?  You might also consider explaining why you need infantry.  If you just want to kill someone or break their stuff, you don't need infantry.  Infantry is if you want to steal their stuff or capture their people.  Is this a well-prepared invasion?  Or a colonization that is trying to convert from self-defense against predators to invasion?

Comment: This question is very broad. Just one example of futuristic "weaponry" for you to think about - [Borg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek)) from Star Trek series.

Answer (score 2):

**Automation/Drones and weapons keyed to the intent of the invasion.**

You mentioned that humans are going to colonize the planet, so any world-ending/hot nuclear options would be off the table.

With how warfare has progressed since WW2 (and the dropping of the first 2 nukes in warfare) Technology has been focused on human-protecting countermeasures, and the weapons needed to bypass them. The endgame for that particular direction of technological advancement would be to remove live humans from the direct line of fire.

1. Drones are remotely controlled, and act as scouts and light target assassins (political figures/unarmored targets/infrastructure).
2. Automated combat suits with onboard limited decision making, piloted remotely by a human in a safe(r) location for patrolling controlled sectors and hard-target removal (as support against entrenched targets, direct against small targets that are armored)
3. Fully automated combat devices (could be tank facsimiles, mechs, drones, etc.) capable of targeting and eradicating full installations. (Primary uses against military only targets, targets not needed after the war is over).

Given the logistics of producing/transporting such weapons at the site of the siege, the preference would be for low-casualty warfare, most likely.

Manufacturing and other heavy infrastructure installations would almost always be taken out by small insurgent strikes, to preserve the hardware while minimizing the casualties on the attacking side.

---

As for the weapons themselves, you would likely see more advanced projectiles, with advances such as molten metal payloads, plasmafied payloads (rail gun is an example), improvements to the round/delivery system to increase muzzle velocity, accuracy, and effective range.

Close advances would include weaponized lasers (increase power output/ focusing to allow for actual near-instantaneous damage), partial-AI missiles with the ability to defeat even some of the most sophisticated anti-missile emplacements, and potentially other forms of radiation based weaponry (lasers being visible or infrared spectrum as an example). Radiation based weaponry could include things like microwave cannons, thermal cannons(a weapon that takes excessive volumes of heat and uses a delivery system to release it on/at/near a target), and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Current trends involve creating "kill webs" of sensors and shooters. Given the very real limits to what a human being can carry (even augmented by exoskeletons), Infantrymen of the future will be festooned with personal and remote sensor devices to locate and identify possible enemy targets.

These infantrymen will be backed by a massive chain of manned and automated fire support platforms on land, sea, in the air and even in orbital space. The massive number of platforms also means that there can be a massive number of different types of rounds to defeat different types of countermeasures that might be present (or simply overwhelm defences by sheer numbers).

The actual infantry will also carry some sort of personal protection weapon. I would suggest that the weapon would be attached to the top of the helmet (something that would allow you to look at a target and shoot them), or a drone that is in close proximity that carries the weapon that can react quickly to the target.